# Is it possible for single thread to run on multiple cores

Tags: multithreading

I wonder if it is possible for a single-threaded program to run on multiple cores?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
       int var1 = x + y;
       int var2 = var1 + 1;
       System.out.println(var1 + var2);
}
```

Just as an example, in the above code since `var2` depends on `var1` so I assume those two lines can't run on different cores because we don't know what would be the order of execution. However, if they don't depend on each other then is it possible that we can run them in parallel? I thought it might be more efficient for some heavy computation problems. Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag... `java`?

Comment: *single threaded* kind of means "not possible to execute on multiple cores simultaneously" so no, it is not possible for a single thread to run on multiple cores (at the same time).  On the other hand it *is* possible, in very many cases, to either convert a single-threaded program to multi-threading, or to replace it by an equivalent multi-threaded program.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Whether something can or cannot be parallelized fully depends on what you are trying to do, on what computations you are trying to implement. There is no general "yes" or "no" answer. Also I don't understand what you mean by "single-threaded program to run on multiple cores". No, this cannot happen. Either something is single-threaded and runs on one core (at least at a time), or it is multi-threaded and may (or may not, depending on scheduler) run on multiple cores.

Comment: Hi @HighPerformanceMark, sorry I didn't realise I made a typo in the code. var2 suppose to euqal (var1+1) which makes it depend on var1. And thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume those two lines can't run on different cores.

You should not trust that assumption. Here is what you can safely assume: You can assume that if a single thread calls `main()`, then the outcome will be the same *as if* the statements were executed in *program order* (I.e., the order in which they appear in the source code.)

The theoretical reason why you should not assume anything about the number of cores is that, whatever language you are talking about, the language specification probably does not say anything about "cores." In some far-out scenario—maybe it will never happen, but who knows?—some highly-advanced build-tool/OS/hardware system could conceivably split up the execution of a single large function by a single thread across multiple "cores." So long as it obeys the guarantee that the outcome will be the same *AS IF* it all was done sequentially by a single core, then everybody should be happy.

The *practical* reason why you should not trust your assumption about the number of cores is, while a thread is executing main, it could be *preempted* at any time by the OS scheduler, and if your program has not requested any *affinity* of its threads for particular cores, then when the scheduler eventually resumes the thread, it could be resumed on any available core.

Comment: You quoted only a piece of OP's sentence, the begining is "in the above code since var2 depends on var1 so I assume those two lines can't run on different cores". Assuming that's the case (even though OP's code actually contradicts that statement) then there's no way to calculate both in parallel. The execution cannot be split across multiple cores, and has to be sequential.

Comment: @freakish, OP may assume that the outcome, when the code is executed by a single thread, will be the same as if the statements were executed in program order. If that limits the ability of some system to execute the statements in parallel, then the statements won't be executed in parallel.

Comment: @freakish your claim is methodically correct, yet having no details about actual composition, your implication, derived from a postulated dependence, is as valid as any other guestimate as may exist such a DAG-computing graph, that permits at least some E2E-computing time improvements if using more than a single stream of pure-[SERIAL] execution of the "whole (blocks) assignment" parts, starting the other only after the first one has been completed.(Theory of Pi-calculus & CSP-systems has shown many such advantages exist on finer-levels of granularity, where [CONCURRENT]-processing may help)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination @SolomonSlow really appreciated

Comment: Hi @user3666197, thanks for your comment, when you say "starting the other only after the first one has been completed" I guess then the program is still executed sequentially rather than in parallel?

Comment: Welcome, @JY999 Comment objects an unsupported claim, that (even if there is some form of dependency of var2 on var1) there may be parts of the computing steps (needed for evaluation of the var2, that are independent of var1) that may be pre-computed before completing the calculus of value & its final assignment to the var1, so not only a pure-[SERIAL], but also some form of safe, controlled [CONCURRENT]-code execution flow is possible (using more than 1 streams of instructions - implementation details depend on language, compiler/interpreter toolchain & target HW capabilities). Details matter

Comment: Sounds cool! Thanks again @user3666197